# How to run Intellij IDEA from terminal in detached mode

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to run Intellij IDEA 2019.2 from terminal in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with command `idea`.

But terminal is stayed connected to IDEA output - IDEA write logs to it.

I've tried to use `&`: `idea &`, but it didn't help - console is still connected to IDEA.

```
romach@romach:~/bin$ idea &
[2] 836
romach@romach:~/bin$ 2019-08-01 15:55:56,253 [   1189]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Docker integration not loaded: until build 182.SNAPSHOT < IU-192.5728.98 
2019-08-01 15:55:56,296 [   1232]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - NodeJS not loaded: until build 191.SNAPSHOT < IU-192.5728.98 
2019-08-01 15:55:56,865 [   1801]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Docker integration not loaded: until build 182.SNAPSHOT < IU-192.5728.98 
2019-08-01 15:55:56,905 [   1841]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - NodeJS not loaded: until build 191.SNAPSHOT < IU-192.5728.98 
2019-08-01 15:56:01,584 [   6520]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: VibrantInk from plugin: com.intellij.database
```

Comment: Haha now I came in here looking for an answer because I think they default to detached now and I want regular.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that idea is still "attached" to the console. It just uses the console as an output.
Try to use `idea > /dev/null 2>&1 &` to redirect the output to `/dev/null`

Comment: This won't prevent the main issue of closing the terminal also closes intellij ide

Comment: @Kaigo
can't confirm. In my case PhpStorm (which is based on Intellij as far as i know) is kept open when redirecting the output as suggested by Feedward and closing the terminal afterwards.

Comment: does not work with pycharm on ubuntu 22

Answer (score 11):

Based on the @Feedforward, I added this lines to my **~/.bashrc** file:

```
function idea() {
    /opt/idea-IC-202.6397.94/bin/idea.sh "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

*Note: replace the second line with the Idea proper path*

With this function, you can open the current directory in Idea as follows:

```
$ idea .
```

Just replace "." with your desired directory

Comment: finally a solution on a M1 macbook pro. The toolbox shell script simply wouldn't work for me on new install of OSX. although this is crude, it works. The other issue of course with this solution is that each time updating intellij one would need to update the path to the new toolbox installed intellij path

Answer (score 6):

First, create the command-line launcher.

**Tools > Create Command-line Launcher...**

That will create `/usr/local/bin/idea`.

Now you can navigate to a project directory and open a project just like you'd be able to do with vscode.

```
$ cd ~/MyProject
$ idea .
$
```

IntelliJ IDEA will open the directory as a project. And your terminal will be ready for your next command.

But the trick to getting this to work is that **IntelliJ IDEA must already be running**.

If IntelliJ IDEA is not currently running, you'll see output printed to your terminal. Your terminal will not be available for additional commands until you close the project (unless you ran it as a background process).

If IntelliJ IDEA is currently running with just its Welcome screen, IntelliJ IDEA will open a new window and load the project.

If IntelliJ IDEA is currently running with one or more projects windows open, IntelliJ IDEA will prompt you for what to do:

[image: Dialog asking where you'd like to open the project]

In situations where you want the editor to wait, add the `-w, --wait` option.

To quickly edit a single file, add the `-e` option, which means [LightEdit mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/lightedit-mode.html).

Answer (score 5):

I was facing similar issue in MacOS, fixed it with below function defined in `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
function idea() {
    open -a "IntelliJ IDEA" "$1"
}
```

**Usage:** `idea .`, `idea README.md` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this problem with RubyMine, and basically the next solution works equally for all of the JetBrains products:

1. Create the script:**Tools > Create Command-line Launcher**
2. Add the next function to .zshrc (it's the same in bash):

   function rubymine() {
   ( mine "$@" & ) > /dev/null 2>&1
   }

Replace rubymine with any other name that you prefer e.g.: *intellij*, and replace mine with your JetBrains product, e.g.: *idea*

It works better than the other mentioned solutions because this moves Rubymine to the background and suppress log messages.

Acknowledgments: [makandracards](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1296-opening-rubymine-projects-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm in windows, and had the same question. The `idea` executable is a batch script in there, which is meant to be run attached to console, as its also the build system command (if you're into that stuff).

The Solution was to invoke the command `idea64`. Which is the actual binary that just launches the app. Linux should have similar behaviour, ideally. MacOS has a better way of getting at it, as @dds101010 mentions.